# How to have a webpage load a random video from my hard drive?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my webpage to load 1 of 6 videos randomly upon loading. The resulting error is the webpage displays the "Can't find file" error inside the webplayer box that the video should appear in. Everything else displays and works as it should.

My file structure is as follows:

```
Root Folder
    js Folder
        videos Folder
            ad1.mp4
            ad2.mp4
            ad3.mp4
            ad4.mp4
            ad5.mp4
            ad6.mp4
        random.js
    Home.html
```

Here is my Home.html code:

```
<body>
...
    <div class="row">
    ...
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="center">            
                    <iframe width="420" height="345" id="video" src="js/videos/">
                        <script src="js/random.js"></script>
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer-distributed">
    ...
    </footer>
</body>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var videoPlayer= document.getElementById('video');

function playIt(
{
    videoPlayer.play();
    var videos = [ "ad1", "ad2", "ad3", "ad4", "ad5", "ad6" ], videos = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
    videoPlayer.src = "videos/" + videos + ".mp4";
}

videoPlayer.addEventListener('ended', playIt, false);
playIt();
```

Comment: have you tried using the video source `videos/` ?

Comment: You need to move the play() to after you change the src, no?

Answer (score 0):

try replace:

```
videoPlayer.src = "../videos/" + videos + ".mp4";
```

to:

```
videoPlayer.src = "videos/" + videos + ".mp4";
```

Because other paths without "../"

As written abouve function should be:

```
function playIt(
{
var videos = [ "ad1", "ad2", "ad3", "ad4", "ad5", "ad6" ], videos = videos[Math.floor(Math.random() * videos.length)];
videoPlayer.src = "videos/" + videos + ".mp4";
videoPlayer.play();
}
```

Comment: my videos are under a different root folder than my javascript file. videoPlayer.src = "../videos/" + videos + ".mp4"; is an attempt to go up one directory and down into the videos folder for the array source.

Comment: So, there may be a problem, that your web page doesn't have access to this folder. Also some web servers remove .., above the root or remove all "..".

Comment: I have moved the videos to a subfolder in my js folder. Now the problem is the media player shows the video files as a directory list.